# Ways to Script creation of AWS resources

Tags: amazon-web-services

What would be the easiest way to script creation of AWS resources.

Currently, I have several SQS'es and Lambdas. Ideally I would like to have it scripted somehow, so we could easily deploy it. I do know about Terraform, but I not sure I would want that.

Comment: Asking what is the "Best" way to do something is too broad and off-topic for this site since what is "best" is a matter of opinion. If you search you will find many methods of "scripting" creation of AWS resources such as Terraform, CloudFormation, AWS CLI, AWS SDKs, etc. Which one is "best" for you will depend on exactly what your specific needs are, and which one you feel most comfortable using.

Comment: That is exactly why I asked people to give their tools that they used. Now I can see each and every one of them and check it against my specific needs... or if I feel comfortable using it :)

Comment: You could have asked what the options are without asking which one is "Best". That's the part that becomes opinionated and will get your question downvoted and closed.

Comment: I have changed the topic name as suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of options in the 'infrastructure as code' space: CDK, CloudFormation, Terraform, Troposphere, Chalice, Serverless, and more.

For one opinion, see [Forming Serverless Clouds with AWS: CloudFormation, SAM, CDK, Amplify](https://www.devalias.net/devalias/2018/09/15/forming-serverless-clouds-aws-cloudformation-sam-cdk-amplify/).

Answer (score 1):

[The Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/) may be what you're looking for.

I have used it extensively in both personal and professional projects and it does just what I need. It's much easier than Terraform and AWS SAM.

All you need to do is modify a `serverless.yml` file. A few lines of .yml code translate into hundreds of lines in a CloudFormation template.

There are a couple of crash courses on [The Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/) around the web, including some very good ones on Udemy. However, The Serverless Framework is easy to pick up, so if you create a function every now and then you should get used to it rather quickly. Their documentation is also very good.

Here's an [example](https://serverless.com/blog/aws-lambda-sqs-serverless-integration/) of how to manage your SQS queues (since you mentioned SQS on the original question)

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution to manage just the Lambdas is to use [AWS Chalice](https://github.com/aws/chalice/). It can create Lambdas, API Gateway, CloudWatch triggers. It can also create triggers for SQS, and SNS for your Lambda functions but can **not** create SQS queue or SNS topics.

This way you can deploy Lambdas incrementally. CD tools can be set up for automatic deployments as well.